# Expanded args ['xv_11_laser_driver'] to: [] when following http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Running%20the%20XV-11%20Node

Tags: ros, xv-11-laser-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

As a beginner, followed the instructions on
http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Running%20the%20XV-11%20Node
to install xv_11 drivers for Neato laser (for beginners, as is marked).
When arriving at step 4, getting into trouble :

~/cwru-ros-pkg$ rosmake --rosdep-install xv_11_laser_driver
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['xv_11_laser_driver']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111208-221941
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['xv_11_laser_driver'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['xv_11_laser_driver']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

is this cwru-ros-pkg broken? Or am I doing something else wrong ?
(note using cturtle : echo $ROS_ROOT gives /opt/ros/cturtle/ros
$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH gives /home/user/cwru-ros-pkg/cwru-ros-pkg:/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks

Thx for any help !

Grtz,
Mvp,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12275/expanded-args-%5B%27xv_11_laser_driver%27%5D-to:-%5B%5D-when-following-http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver/tutorials/running%20the%20xv-11%20node/) by [mvp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1509/mvp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `xv_11_laser_driver` was accidentally removed from the cwru-ros-pkg repository. It has since been restored, so the directions should work again.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0